# Issue in include css and javascript files

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

If i use CDN hosted javascript and css url inside my html it works. If i use local folder location inside my project its not working. Find the below code for reference. I have the content from the below mentioned CDN url only. Kindly advice what i am doing wrong.

Below code not working, if i mentioned my local path for js and css,  but i am using the below url code only in my project css and javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#home" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works if i use CDN url for js and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#home" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML file located?

Comment: check filepath and browser console..

Comment: Where is your HTML file located ??

Comment: html file located in the root path of the project For Example: project/index.html, js & css foolder are inside project/

Comment: js and css files path is relative to this html file, if you are using chrome then do inspect element on page and in network tab check if your file is loaded properly.

Comment: View page source and click on the path for your local css and js and if source load correctly then there wont be any problem at all.. else check for any typo with your file names.

Comment: How do you know the files aren't loading?? Use `Firebug (Net Tab)`

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS and JS folders are placed in the root directory, then add a slash to the start.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should be able to open the files like this http://localhost/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css. It doesn't work? hmm...

Comment: There is some file name issue, that why is not loading correctly